# How to search user contributions by both upper and lower case character username in MediaWiki 1.20.0?

Tags: php, mysql, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I am using MediaWiki 1.20.0 and I am finding the way to search user contributions by both upper and lower case character username.

Example:

If the username is: **SomeOne**

By default, MediaWiki accept these to search: **SomeOne, someOne**

But I also want MediaWiki to accept these: **someone, Someone, SOMEONE, SOMEone...**

Comment: Update for my solution.

Comment: I hope you're ensuring that no "duplicate" usernames are created, too, or it will be a mess. I guess that needs patching AntiSpoof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP's answer: I have found the solution. Share this for everyone.

- Open file `./includes/User.php`
- Find

  ```
  $s = $dbr->selectRow( 'user', array( 'user_id' ), array( 'user_name' => $nt->getText() ), __METHOD__ );
  ```
- Replace with

  ```
  //congminh1709 - Ignore lower and upper case to search username START
  global $wgContLang;
  $s = $dbr->selectRow( 'user', array( 'user_id' ), array('lower(convert(user_name using latin1))' => $wgContLang->lc($nt->getText())) , __METHOD__ );
  //Original Select
  //$s = $dbr->selectRow( 'user', array( 'user_id' ), array( 'user_name' => $nt->getText()) , __METHOD__ );                
  //congminh1709 - Ignore lower and upper case to search username STOP
  ```
- Save file